# When a magnetic ball passes through a copper pipe vertically

Tags: magnetic-fields, electromagnetic-induction, lenz-law

Let's say a magnetic ball passes through a hollow pipe, which is a conductor (copper), vertically. We can observe that its acceleration is decreased when compared to a free gravitational fall.

By Faraday's and Lenz's law, this is due to the change in the magnetic flux of the copper pipe, which in turn produces a magnetic field opposite in direction to the direction of the magnetic field created by the magnetic ball to stay in equilibrium.
This force opposes the gravitational force acting on the magnetic ball.

In this application, I am unable to visualize the vectors involved to understand this mechanism in a more detailed way. Kindly help me out with this and provide a diagrammatic representation if possible :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms compare your arrangement to a vertical solenoid with the ends connected together and a magnet dropping through it.
An induced current passes through the solenoid which sets up a magnetic field to opposite the motion of the falling magnet.

Now consider a vertical solenoid with one complete turn.
An induced current passes through the one complete turn which sets up a magnetic field to opposite the motion of the falling magnet.

Now a whole series of one turn solenoids stacked on top of one another.
Induced currents pass through some of the complete turns which set up a magnetic field to opposite the motion of the falling magnet.

Finally consider a whole series of one turn solenoids stacked on top of one another and connected electrical together - a vertical conducting cylindrical pipe.
Induced currents pass through the pipe which set up a magnetic field to opposite the motion of the falling magnet.